# Why won't this JavaScript function fire?

Tags: javascript

I wrote a small hash change object, it will alert the url hash whenever it changes:

```
(function() {

    function hashChange() {
        this.previousHash;
        this.initialize();
    }

    hashChange.prototype.initialize = function() {
        this.setInterval = window.setInterval(this.checkHashChange, 0);
    }

    hasChange.prototype.uponHashChange = function(hash) {
        alert('I executed!');
        var hashValue = hash.split('#')[1];
        alert(hashValue);
    }

    hashChange.prototype.checkHashChange = function() {
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        if(hash && hash !== this.previousHash) {
            this.previousHash = hash;
            this.uponHashChange(hash); // <---- doesn't execute
        }
    }

    var hashChange = new hashChange();

})();
```

But this:

```
this.uponHashChange(hash);
```

Never gets executed. Why?

Comment: checkHashChange will run in the context of the global object. You need something like Function.bind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
this.setInterval = window.setInterval(this.checkHashChange, 0);
```

This line is not going to do exactly what you mean. `this.checkHashChange` will lose its binding to its current `this` (which would be a `hashChange` instance), and will instead be invoked in the context of the `window` object.

You need to bind it explicitly to the correct context object:

```
var self = this;
this.setInterval = window.setInterval(function() { self.checkHashChange() }, 0);
```

Matt Greer has suggested `Function.bind`, which would make it more concise and likely more readable:

```
this.setInterval = window.setInterval(checkHashChange.bind(this), 0);
```

Unfortunately, `Function.bind` is not yet widely supported across browsers.

Comment: ok but none of this changes the issue with that non executing method: `TypeError: this.uponHashChange is not a function`, same error even if I store this inside a variable and reference it that way: `TypeError: self.uponHashChange is not a function`

Comment: Please post your updated code, I have no way to know how you have altered your code, considering I haven't advised you to change your `uponHashChange` invocation at all.

Comment: wait never mind, it works now. The bind method wasn't working but the 1st suggestion works. The bind method was giving the uponHashChange error.